# utf-8 in mysql & php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

i am really confused with the UTF-8, displaying "Ä", "Ö", "Ü" and such.

On my page i have a form where the user can enter a message. This text is supposed to be stored in a mysql database and loaded from the database to show on the screen.

These symbols are not properly stored in the mysql database and if i manually change them in the database they are not printed properly after i fetch them. I dont understand how to get this to work.

`mysql_set_charset("utf-8");`Doesn't work somehow, and i probably dont know how to use it properly. Same with the encoding / decoding. Could you please enlighten me on the concept of how to properly handle those "Umlauts" and the UTF-8?

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL calls it `utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query before your actual query to set everything to utf8:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);
```

Hope this will help you. :D

Comment: What is $conn ? is it $conn = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database); ?

Comment: yup, it is a mysql connection